# ConceptNet: simple query locally

Tags: python, conceptnet

I am completely new to ConceptNet.

How can I query it for the same data that [the web API](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/API) provides, but locally? What is the function that is called behind the web API field?

Comment: Which version of conceptnet are you using? Did you build run the build script?